# boost.interprocessでの複雑な構造体ベクターと型変換についてコンパイルエラーがあります。

Tags: c++, ubuntu, opencv, boost

正月明けにすみません。
 "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33513051/structures-and-vectors-in-boost-shared-memory"という質問にある
"http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0ab21481b69d87bb" にあるコードを書き換えて
コードを書いています。
しかしながら、私はc++の経験はおろか、プログラミングが全くできない関係もあり、

```
data.push_back(id);   // 14 line in main function
```

auto&型のdataという変数でマッチングしないというコンパイルエラーが出てきてしまいました。

```
auto& data = Shared::locate(smt);   // 10 line in "while(1)" of main function
```

呼び出し元は上記のところです。

正直言ってコンパイルエラーにだけならないように書き換えてきたので、エラーはここだけではないと思います。
そういうことなので全てのコードを掲載させていただきます。

どうかお助力のほうをお願いいたします。
（最終的に共有メモリ内のvectorにミリ秒とOpenCVのMatのuchar*変換とmemcpyのコピー用サイズを格納して子プロセスで一括で取りたいがために書いたコードです。）

```
//  opencv's lib    
#include <cv.h>
#include <cxcore.h>
#include <highgui.h>
//  opencv's lib end
#include <string>
#include <boost/interprocess/managed_shared_memory.hpp>

#include <boost/interprocess/managed_mapped_file.hpp> // use for Coliru
#include <boost/interprocess/containers/vector.hpp>   // boost/containers/vector.hpp
#include <boost/interprocess/containers/string.hpp>   // boost/containers/string.hpp
#include <iostream>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <stdio.h>

 //                                                                    void_allocator;
namespace bip = boost::interprocess;

typedef unsigned char uchar;
//Typedefs of allocators and containers
typedef bip::managed_shared_memory::segment_manager                       segment_manager_t;
typedef bip::allocator<void, segment_manager_t>  void_allocator;

typedef void_allocator::rebind<uchar>::other                           uchar_allocator;
typedef bip::vector<uchar, uchar_allocator>                                   uchar_vector;



template <typename Alloc = std::allocator<char> >
struct BasicInData {

    public:
        BasicInData(Alloc alloc = {}) : image(alloc)
        { }

        template <typename T>
        BasicInData(double x, int sizeImg, uchar_vector& image, Alloc alloc = {}) :
            x(x), sizeImg(sizeImg), image(alloc)
        { }

        double x = 0;
        int sizeImg = 0;
        uchar_vector image;
};

using InData = BasicInData<>; // just heap allocated

namespace Shared {
    using segment                      = bip::managed_shared_memory;
    using segment_manager              = segment::segment_manager;

    template <typename T> using alloc  = bip::allocator<T, segment_manager>;
    template <typename T> using vector = bip::vector<T, alloc<T> >;

    using InData = BasicInData<alloc<char> >; // shared memory version

    vector<InData>& locate(segment& smt) {
        auto* v = smt.find_or_construct<vector<InData> >("InDataVector")(smt.get_segment_manager());
        assert(v);
        return *v;
    }
}


int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    if(argc == 1){ //Parent process
        struct timeval tv;
        // there are making no sense 2 line in below, just examine
        gettimeofday(&tv, NULL);
        double time = ((double)tv.tv_usec/1000000);
        // Remove shared memory on construction and destruction

        // Create a new segment with given name and size
        struct shm_remove
        {
            shm_remove(){bip::shared_memory_object::remove("MySharedMemory");}
            ~shm_remove(){bip::shared_memory_object::remove("MySharedMemory");}
        }remover;
        Shared::segment smt(bip::create_only,"MySharedMemory", 65536); // 65536 for coliru
        auto& data = Shared::locate(smt);
        //Shared::alloc bip::alloc_inst (data);
        // Camera Capture 
        cv::Mat_<cv::Vec3b> mat;
        cv::VideoCapture vcap(0);

        InData id;
        // camera open check
        if (!vcap.isOpened())
            return -1;

        while (1) { // while keyboard key push
            vcap >> mat; // camera to mat
            int image_size = mat.total() * mat.elemSize();
            id.sizeImg = image_size;
            id.image.resize(image_size * sizeof(uchar));
            memcpy(&id.image[0], mat.data, image_size * sizeof(uchar));
            // get microsecond by double
            gettimeofday(&tv, NULL);
            double time = ((double)tv.tv_usec/1000000);
            id.x = time;
            data.push_back(id);
            if(cv::waitKey(30) >= 0) break; // keyboard pushed
        }
        //Launch child process
        std::string s(argv[0]); s += " child";
        if(0 != std::system(s.c_str()))
            return 1;

        // check child has destroyed the vector
        if(segment.find<vector<InData>>("InDataVector").first)
            return 1;
        }
    }else{
        // Open the managed segment
        managed_shared_memory segment(open_only, "MySharedMemory");

        // Find the vector 
        vector<InData> *myvector = segment.find<vector<InData>>("InDataVector").first;
        // Use vector in reverse order

        vector<InData>::iterator it;

        cv::Mat_<cv::Vec3b> im;
        for(it = myvector->begin(); it !=myvector->end(); ++it){
            im.resize(it->sizeImg);
            memcpy(im.data, &imref[0], it->sizeImg);
            cv::imshow("window1", im);
        }

        segment.destroy<vector<InData>>("InDataVector");

        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: 「プログラミングが全くできない」ということはこの質問に対するゴールは何でしょうか？ プログラミングの依頼であれば[crowdworks](https://crowdworks.jp/)のようなサイトの方が適切に感じます。

Comment: 「私はc++の経験はおろか、プログラミングが全くできない」という本人の記述は重要であり消すべきではないと考えました。回答によりコンパイルエラーが解消したとしても、コードの意味が理解できているとは思えないため、質問のゴールがどこにあるかが重要に思います。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`id`は`Shared`名前空間の`InData`型である必要がありますが，グローバル名前空間の`InData`型になってしまっています．なので，

```
InData id;
```

を

```
Shared::InData id;
```

にするととりあえずこのコンパイルエラーは直ります．
ただ，このままgccでコンパイルすると`error: could not convert ‘<brace-enclosed initializer list>()’ from ‘<brace-enclosed initializer list>’ to ‘boost::interprocess::allocator<char, boost::interprocess::segment_manager<char, boost::interprocess::rbtree_best_fit<boost::interprocess::mutex_family>, boost::interprocess::iset_index> >’`というエラーが出ます．
これは`Shared::InData`構造体のコンストラクタが`alloc={}`となっているのが正しくないためです．なので，

```
Shared::InData id(smt.get_segment_manager());
```

とすると無事コンパイルできるはずです．

C++に慣れている人にプログラムの作成を依頼されることを強くお勧めします．

Comment: 助かりました。ありがとうございます。