# Boost shared memory でのアロケートがうまく行かない？

Tags: c++, boost, memory-leaks, nullpointerexception

uchar*のvectorを保持する構造体のvectorのアロケートがどうしてもうまく行きません。
main関数内のwhileの処理終了後にエラーが出ます。

main関数のwhileに入る前に

```
auto &data = Shared::locate(smt);
```

を実行したら必ずWhile文終了後にエラーになります。(core dump)
このエラーは何を意味しているのか検索しても出てきません。
どういうときに出るエラーなのですか？

[image: よくわからないエラー]

```
#include <cv.h>
#include <cxcore.h>
#include <highgui.h>
#include <boost/interprocess/managed_shared_memory.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/managed_mapped_file.hpp> // use for Coliru
#include <boost/interprocess/containers/vector.hpp>   // boost/containers/vector.hpp
#include <boost/interprocess/containers/string.hpp>   // boost/containers/string.hpp
#include <iostream>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <stdio.h>

 //                                                                    void_allocator;
namespace bip = boost::interprocess;

typedef unsigned char uchar;
//Typedefs of allocators and containers
typedef bip::managed_shared_memory::segment_manager                       segment_manager_t;
typedef bip::allocator<void, segment_manager_t>  void_allocator;

typedef void_allocator::rebind<uchar>::other                           uchar_allocator;
typedef bip::vector<uchar, uchar_allocator>                                   uchar_vector;



template <typename Alloc = std::allocator<uchar> >
struct BasicInData {

    public:
        BasicInData(Alloc alloc = {}) : image(alloc)
        { }

        template <typename T>
        BasicInData(double x, int sizeImg, uchar_vector& image, Alloc alloc = {}) :
            x(x), sizeImg(sizeImg), image(alloc)
        { }

        double x = 0;
        int sizeImg = 0;
        uchar_vector image;
};

using InData = BasicInData<>; // just heap allocated

namespace Shared {
    using segment                      = bip::managed_shared_memory;
    using segment_manager              = segment::segment_manager;

    template <typename T> using alloc  = bip::allocator<T, segment_manager>;
    template <typename T> using vector = bip::vector<T, alloc<T> >;

    using InData = BasicInData<alloc<uchar> >; // shared memory version

    vector<InData>& locate(segment& smt) {
        auto* v = smt.find_or_construct<vector<InData> >("InDataVector")(smt.get_segment_manager());
        assert(v);
        return *v;
    }
}


int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    if(argc == 1){ //Parent process
        // Remove shared memory on construction and destruction
        bip::shared_memory_object::remove("MySharedMemory");
        // Create a new segment with given name and size
        struct timeval tv;
        gettimeofday(&tv, NULL);
        struct shm_remove
        {
            shm_remove(){bip::shared_memory_object::remove("MySharedMemory");}
            ~shm_remove(){bip::shared_memory_object::remove("MySharedMemory");}
        }remover;
        Shared::segment smt(bip::create_only,"MySharedMemory", 100000000);
        auto &data = Shared::locate(smt);
        //Shared::alloc bip::alloc_inst (data);

        cv::Mat_<cv::Vec3b> mat;
        cv::VideoCapture vcap(0);

        Shared::InData id(smt.get_segment_manager());


        if (!vcap.isOpened())
            return -1;
        char count = 0;
        while (1) {
            vcap >> mat;
            printf ("count: %d \n", count); count++;
            int image_size = mat.total() * mat.elemSize();
            printf ("size: %d \n", image_size);
            id.sizeImg = image_size;
            printf ("id's sizeImg: %d \n", id.sizeImg * sizeof(uchar));
            id.image.resize(image_size * sizeof(uchar));
            int totalSize = image_size * sizeof(uchar);
            printf ("count: %d \n", count);
            memcpy(&id.image[0], mat.data, image_size * sizeof(uchar));
            //Launch child process
            gettimeofday(&tv, NULL);
            double time = ((double)tv.tv_usec/1000000);
            id.x = time;
            data.push_back(id);
            if((100000000 / count) <= (totalSize*20)){ printf("Getting video data done"); break; }
        }

        std::string s(argv[0]); s += " child";
        if(0 != std::system(s.c_str()))
            return 1;

        // check child has destroyed the vector
        if(smt.find<Shared::vector<InData>>("InDataVector").first)
            return 1;

    } else{
        // Open the managed segment
        bip::managed_shared_memory segment(bip::open_only, "MySharedMemory");

        // Find the vector using c-string name
        bip::vector<InData> *myvector = segment.find<bip::vector<InData>>("InDataVector").first;
        // Use vector in reverse order

        bip::vector<InData>::iterator it;

        cv::Mat_<cv::Vec3b> im;
        for(it = myvector->begin(); it !=myvector->end(); ++it){
            im.resize(it->sizeImg);
            memcpy(im.data, &it->image[0], it->sizeImg);
            cv::imshow("window1", im);
        }

        segment.destroy<bip::vector<InData>>("InDataVector");

        return 0;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: [先のスレッド](http://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/31583/4236)で「『プログラミングが全くできない』ということはこの質問に対するゴールは何でしょうか？」と尋ねましたが返答がなく不明なままです。それは別スレッドでのことなので構わないとも思いましたが、本スレッドでも「アロケートがどうしてもうまく行きません」と状況説明だけで回答として求める質問が書かれておらず、やはりゴールが不明なようです。何を求めているのか明確にすべきと考えます。

Comment: わかりました。質問を修正します。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> While文終了後にエラーになります。(core dump)
>   このエラーは何を意味しているのか検索しても出てきません。
>   どういうときに出るエラーなのですか？

プログラムの実行中に回復不可能なエラーが発生し、実行を中止せざるを得ない場合に、デバッグを目的としてメモリ状態一式を保存してからプログラムを終了させます。ここで保存された情報をコアファイルと呼び、保存する行為をコアダンプと呼びます。

ですので、回復不可能なエラーが発生したことしかわからず、どのようなエラーが発生したのかはコアファイルの解析（デバッグ）が必要になります。